# I want to save data input somewhere I can use it after restart

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the following code in HTML. It's a form that uses Angular to allow a user to populate data.

This is the part in the form where data is populated:

```
<setting-item *ngFor="let household of households; let i = 
index;"
[hasTariff]="paymentType==1"
[values]="household.toObject()"
(changeValue)="changeValue($event, i)" ></setting-item>
```

and this is the part in the form where data is sent:

```
<div fxFlex="20" fxLayoutAlign="end end">
   <button (click)="sendHouseholdValues()"
     md-raised-button class="save-btn">SAVE</button>
</div>
```

I want to save each value when it is sent.
the code for sendHouseholdValues is as follows:

```
sendHouseholdValues()
{
  this.householdSettingService.setHouseholdsValue(this.households, 
  !this.isSetting, this.paymentType);
  this.cancel();
}
```

Comment: might consider.. http://pamblam.github.io/jSQL/

Comment: You cou also use localStorage